# How to specify the layers to be "fine-tuned" in TF object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I followed the steps on TF object detection API tutorial page using the ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config configuration at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config

It is very cool that I am able to train a custom detector using my own images. However, as the whole training process appears to me as a "black-box", I am wondering how I could configure the layers to be fine-tuned, just like how one could configure the layers to be retrained using an Inception model in tensorflow/keras.

I think that the layers to be fine-tuned could(should) be different if I had, say, 10000 images rather than 100 images.

Answer (score 7):

To fine tune a specific layer, you have to freeze the rest. If you know the name of the layers of your model you want to freeze, than you can add them to the `freeze_variables` ([Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/538f89c4121803645fe72f41ebfd7069c706d954/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto#L51)) in the train part of your config file.and add '*' in front of '.FeatureExtractor.'

For example, this:

```
train_config: {
...
freeze_variables: ".*FeatureExtractor."
}
```

will freeze all layers of the `Feature Extractor` of Faster R-CNN architecture.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  If I print the variable names, they look like: "FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/beta". So why the star before "FeatureExtractor"?

Comment: Hi. Long time ago, but I think I did this just to be sure, that I freeze every variable which has the "FeatureExtractor" part in its name. If you don't have any variables with a prefix before that, you can leave it out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking because I want to freeze the box predictor as opposed to the feature extractor. the box predictor variables look like "BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/weights" or  "BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases". So I've used ".*BoxPredictor*." but that does not seem to work..

Comment: What do yo mean with "it does not seem to work"? Are the variables named differently or are the results not as you expect them. By thinking about it shortly I can not really imagine a scenario where it is a good idea to freeze the box predictor but training the feature extractor

Comment: by "not seem to work" i mean that all layers seem to be trained (as opposed toexcluding the box predictor). and you are right, the only reason i am doing this is to confirm an assumption that training the classifier improves the net's performance a lot while training the feature extractor does not so much.  so just to have a comparison